# HTML, Bootstrap, CSS: Fixed div as Header - Remove transparency

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have created a header div with `position: fixed;`, but it is transparent, so when the user scrolls the page content scrolls through the "header". I have tried adding `opacity: 1` to my header div, but that just makes the entire div white and I cannot see anything inside the header. How do I make the header "solid"?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QzTU9/8/

**Code:**

```
<div id="topHeader" style="position: fixed;">
    <div class="row" style="height: 85px;">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            {% if app.request.get('_route') == 'home' %}<img src="{{asset('images/logo/logo3.png')}}" style="max-height: 90px; max-width: 100%;">
            {% elseif app.request.get('_route') == 'products' %}<img src="{{asset('images/logo/logo3.png')}}" style="max-height: 90px;">
            {% elseif app.request.get('_route') == 'register' %}<img src="{{asset('images/logo/logo3.png')}}" style="max-height: 90px;">
            {% elseif app.request.get('_route') == 'who_we_are' %}<img src="{{asset('images/logo/logo1.png')}}" style="max-height: 90px;">
            {% elseif app.request.get('_route') == 'contact' %}<img src="{{asset('images/logo/logo1.png')}}" style="max-height: 90px;">
            {% elseif app.request.get('_route') == 'testimonials' %}<img src="{{asset('images/logo/logo1.png')}}" style="max-height: 90px;">
            {% elseif app.request.get('_route') == 'how' %}<img src="{{asset('images/logo/logo2.png')}}" style="max-height: 90px;">
            {% elseif app.request.get('_route') == 'faq' %}<img src="{{asset('images/logo/logo2.png')}}" style="max-height: 90px;">
            {% else %}<img src="{{asset('images/logo/logo4.png')}}" style="max-height: 90px;">{% endif %}   
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-5"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <form role="form" class="form form-horizontal form-login" id="loginForm" style="font-size: 10px;">
                <br>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">  
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" id="username" name="_username" class="form-control small-input" placeholder="USERNAME" data-validation-error-msg="Please enter username" data-validation="length" data-validation-length="min1">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" id="password" name="_password" class="form-control small-input" placeholder="PASSWORD" data-validation-error-msg="Please enter password" data-validation="length" data-validation-length="min1">
                        </div>
                    </div>  
                    <div class="col-sm-3" style="text-align: right; padding-right: 0px;"><button style="width: 83px;" class="btn btn-default small-input"> LOGIN </button></div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
                    <div class="col-sm-8 text-center"><br style="font-size: 6px;"><a style="font-size: 12px;" onclick="$('#forgotPassword').modal('show');">FORGOT LOGIN DETAILS</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3" style="text-align: right; padding-right: 0px;">
                        <a class="btn btn-default btn-sm" href="{{url('register')}}"> NEW USER </a> 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 text-center" style="font-size: 88%;">
            <span {% if app.request.get('_route') == 'home' %} style="color: black; font-weight: bold;" {%endif%}>
                {% if app.request.get('_route') != 'home' %}<a href="{{url('home')}}">HOME</a>
                {%else%} HOME {%endif%}
            </span> &nbsp; __ &nbsp;
            <span {% if app.request.get('_route') == 'who_we_are' %} style="color: black; font-weight: bold;" {%endif%}>
                {% if app.request.get('_route') != 'who_we_are' %}<a href="{{url('who_we_are')}}">WHAT IS LITTLE GIANT?</a>
                {%else%} WHAT IS LITTLE GIANT? {%endif%}
            </span> &nbsp; __ &nbsp;
            <span {% if app.request.get('_route') == 'how' %} style="color: black; font-weight: bold;" {%endif%}>
                {% if app.request.get('_route') != 'how' %}<a href="{{url('how')}}">HOW DOES IT WORK?</a>
                {%else%} HOW DOES IT WORK? {%endif%}
            </span> &nbsp; __ &nbsp;
            <span {% if app.request.get('_route') == 'products' %} style="color: black; font-weight: bold;" {%endif%}>
                {% if app.request.get('_route') != 'products' %}<a href="{{url('products')}}">PRODUCTS</a>
                {%else%} PRODUCTS {%endif%}
            </span> &nbsp; __ &nbsp;
            <span {% if app.request.get('_route') == 'testimonials' %} style="color: black; font-weight: bold;" {%endif%}>
                {% if app.request.get('_route') != 'testimonials' %}<a href="{{url('testimonials')}}">SEE WHAT OTHERS SAY ABOUT US</a>
                {%else%} SEE WHAT OTHERS SAY ABOUT US {%endif%}
            </span> &nbsp; __ &nbsp;
            <span {% if app.request.get('_route') == 'faq' %} style="color: black; font-weight: bold;" {%endif%}>
                {% if app.request.get('_route') != 'faq' %}<a href="{{url('faq')}}">FAQ</a>
                {%else%} FAQ {%endif%}
            </span> &nbsp; __ &nbsp;
            <spa {% if app.request.get('_route') == 'register' %} style="color: black; font-weight: bold;" {%endif%}> 
                {% if app.request.get('_route') != 'register' %}<a href="{{url('register')}}">REGISTER</a>
                {%else%} REGISTER {%endif%}
            </span> &nbsp; __ &nbsp;
            <span {% if app.request.get('_route') == 'contact' %} style="color: black; font-weight: bold;" {%endif%}> 
                {% if app.request.get('_route') != 'contact' %}<a href="{{url('contact')}}">CONTACT US</a>
                {%else%} CONTACT US {%endif%}
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Original:**

[image]

**When scrolling:**

[image]

Comment: just a tip for the future, dont just copy and paste your code into the fiddle, try to simplify it only including the necessary parts and dummy text for everything else.  the fiddle you provided is so junked up its practically useless

Comment: Sorry, I did simplify it and removed the TWIG "junk", but I forgot to update it. http://jsfiddle.net/QzTU9/8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may just be a z-index issue

try adding

```
z-index: 9999;
```

to your fixed header div

Comment: Added `z-index: 2;` and `background-color: white;` and that seemed to fix the problem.